# GCP cloud ml-engine start job issue

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am running the below code in GCP default VM and `config.yaml` also created with necessary fields. Although I am getting source directory is not a valid directory error.

> gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training my_job \ --module-name
>   trainer.task \ --staging-bucket gs://my-bucket \ --package-path
>   /my/code/path/trainer \ --packages additional-dep1.tar.gz,dep2.whl

Have checked all the paths and they are ok and the data is within them however the command is not executing...

Help on above topic is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your Python package structure is probably missing an **init**.py.  see http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html
And verify it using setup.py sdist